# Is gradle sync only required to find and correctly import libraries or not

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

This question might be really stupid. But still I think still it can be shared with experts. Android studio imports dependent libraries through gradle sync (If my understanding is not wrong).
 **But can a developer make sure that his code is not monitored or tracked through this process?** 
Do we have some other technique to import custom libraries?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080380/what-gradle-tasks-does-idea-android-studio-run-when-i-press-sync-now-and-the  There is nothing like tracking code here.

Comment: Any official references available about this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Gradle sync feature does just what it says: "Sync project with Gradle files". It creates/updates the Android Studio (IntelliJ IDEA) project files so it will be able to show/manage/compile the project(s) as defined in the Gradle script(s).

If you don't or cannot trust this and you want to be absolutely 100% certain that there's no way to copy your code to the internet, you'll have to program on a computer that does not have internet access.
You can copy all the dependencies to a USB stick, verify that it is secure (no virusses/trojans/etc.) and then copy it to your secure offline computer. You can go to http://search.maven.org and find many dependencies there. There are even hashes available to confirm that your downloads are not tampered with.

In Gradle, you can include those dependencies like this:

```
dependencies {
  compile files('libs/*.jar')
}
```

You can also put Gradle in "offline mode" through the Android Studio project settings. This will disable checking for new versions of libraries online.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a new dependency in gradle it downloads the actual jar from the maven central repository(usually) or in some other place you would have mentioned thats it